# Capturing string until end of line with Boost.Spirit.Qi

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to write a custom struct to capture string until EOL or EOS as part of a larger grammar but I couldn't compile it. I followed [tutorial code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/employee.cpp), yet I couldn't figure out errors in the below snippet.

```cpp
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <cassert>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace project {

struct RawValue {
    std::string str;
};

}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(project::RawValue, str)

namespace project::parser {

struct RawValueParser : qi::grammar<std::string::const_iterator, RawValue(), qi::space_type> {
  RawValueParser() : RawValueParser::base_type(expr) {
    using qi::blank;
    using qi::char_;
    using qi::eol;
    using qi::lexeme;

    expr %= lexeme[*(char_ - eol) >> (char_ - blank)];
  }

  qi::rule<iterator_type, RawValue(), skipper_type> expr;
};

}

int main() {
  project::parser::RawValueParser expr;
  project::RawValue result;
  std::string s1 = "test1";
  auto iter = s1.cbegin();
  auto end = s1.cend();
  assert(qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, expr, qi::space, result));
  return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/PjaaYwO0Qz18998y

This should be a fairly simple example. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error originates here:

```
test.cpp|21 col 58| required from here
/home/sehe/custom/spirit/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/grammar.hpp|77 col 13| error: static assertion failed: incompatible_start_rule
||    77 |             BOOST_SPIRIT_ASSERT_MSG(
||       |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If you go to the indicated location (see also [How do I grok boost spirit compiler errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000730/how-do-i-grok-boost-spirit-compiler-errors/13008735#13008735)):

```
// If you see the assertion below failing then the start rule
// passed to the constructor of the grammar is not compatible with
// the grammar (i.e. it uses different template parameters).
BOOST_SPIRIT_ASSERT_MSG(
    (is_same<start_type, rule<Iterator_, T1_, T2_, T3_, T4_> >::value)
  , incompatible_start_rule, (rule<Iterator_, T1_, T2_, T3_, T4_>));
```

That's your problem. The grammar is `<It, RawValue(), qi::space_type>` but the start rule is `<iterator_type, RawValue(), skipper_type>`, where

```
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<It, iterator_type>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<qi::space_type, skipper_type>);
    qi::space_type _y = skipper_type{};
```

reveals that the second assert fails. The third line leads to more detail diagnostic: **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6606b3d86c139f8f)**

```
test.cpp|33 col 29| error: could not convert ‘boost::spirit::qi::grammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, project::RawValue(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0> >::skipper_type{}’ from ‘boost::spirit::qi::grammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, project::RawValue(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0> >::skipper_type’ {aka ‘boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >’} to ‘boost::spirit::standard::space_type’ {aka ‘boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::te
||    33 |         qi::space_type _y = skipper_type{};
||       |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
||       |                             |
||       |                             boost::spirit::qi::grammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, project::RawValue(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >, 0> >::skipper_type {aka boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard> >}
```

You can tease the whole thing apart, but suffice it to say that your assumption that `skipper_type` would equal the third template argument was wrong.

Simply spell the types you expect out: **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ad6aa3ea06ce85b)**

```
qi::rule<It, RawValue(), qi::space_type> expr;
```

### Side Notes

1. `lexeme` disables the skipper. Consider simplifying the whole thing with that in mind: **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4abfd130015da7a4)** (see also [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))
2. `operator %=` has no meaning wihtout semantic actions
3. `expr` seems a misnomer
4. negated character classes are more efficient than subtracted parsers; did you mean `(char_ - blank)` to mean more than `eol`?
5. End of input is now not accepted instead of eol. Perhaps you should allow it.  I'd write it like

   ```
   start = *~qi::char_("\n\r") >> (eol | eoi);
   ```

### Simplified Listing

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44b5196404b89d27)**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using It = std::string::const_iterator;

struct RawValue { std::string str; };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(RawValue, str)

struct RawValueParser : qi::grammar<It, RawValue()> {
    RawValueParser() : RawValueParser::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;
        start = *~qi::char_("\n\r") >> (eol | eoi);
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, RawValue()> start;
};

int main() {
    RawValueParser expr;

    for (std::string const s : {
             "test1",
             " test2\tbla   \n",
         }) {

        RawValue result;
        std::cout
            << std::boolalpha
            //<< qi::phrase_parse(begin(s), end(s), expr, qi::space, result)
            << qi::parse(begin(s), end(s), expr, result) << " -> "
            << std::quoted(result.str) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
true -> "test1"
true -> " test2 bla   "
```

Comment: Thank you. Much better. My experience with qi has been having it accidentally worked at best for now. :-) I was trying to strip the match as well. I could left-strip the match by prepending `omit[*nonl_space]`. Is there an idiomatic way I could right-strip it as well? This is what I tried, but I couldn't append `tail`'s attribute to the `head`: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5464205a7292572 (This might prompt a separate question though. If so please let me know.)

Comment: I might do it like this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a9aad30ed95d820, but there's no shame in keeping the grammar simpler like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdf1041e18b12794